# How to display/read bitmap in ASP.net web application C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aforge

```
    protected void btnSTart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      cam = new 
      VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
      cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
      cam.Start();
    }

    private void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bit = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        //pictureBox1.image = bitmap;
        //This last line of code was used in C# window console
    }
```

I am using aforge to do a video through my laptop's webcam. The webcam is working fine, but I just can't seem to find a way to display the bitmap. Do I have to use the asp Image or some other control do it and how do I use that control to do so? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP.NET application, the C# is executed on the server. This means that you need a way of getting the image back to the client. This can be done in a few ways (for example, cache the resulting image and provide an endpoint to the client to be able to download it).

Here is an [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) on getting dynamically generated images to the client. Not sure about which version of ASP.NET you are using, but the concepts will be fairly similar.